# Nuget packages with common Names

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I was playing with NuGet so I created a project, wrote two simple functions (multiply and add), packaged it with the following spec:

```
<metadata>
    <id>Math</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
    <tags>Matematica, Test</tags>
</metadata>
```

Then publicized it on my local NuGet.Server feed, added my new nuget package in another sample project, started it and it returns this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Math, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-GB, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Googled for various time but found nothing (was I the only dumb enough to call a temporary package 'Math'?), so I imagined that somewhat my module name was *taboo*, changed it into Math_Test, same source code and it worked like a charm.

Is there some more informations out there that specifies which values are *taboo*?
I can't find anything on nuget official documentation.

The class Math is specified in the following dll (mscorlib.dll) so it doesn't even have the same id...

```
#region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v4.0.0.0
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
#endregion
```

EDIT: 
And here is the code of the sample application

```
using Math;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = -1;
            try
            {
                Common e = new Math.Common();
                a = e.Multiply(3, 2);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.Out.Write(e);
            }

            System.Console.Out.Write(a);
            System.Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: massimo: enable diagnostic output from options and check to see what is conflicting

Comment: @ShyamalDesai : hi, I'm a bit confused, where or how can I do that? The console application goes in error as soon as it starts, I updated the sample code in the question

Comment: tools->options->Projects And Solutions->Build And run: on that page there is an option for MSBuild that defines output verbosity (drop town). Select diagnostic to find the culprit. It will emit a lot, so expect to spend some time to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Shyamal, thanks to you I was able to find the culprit and fixed the issue. I posted the answer if you are curious about what caused the exception

Comment: thanks for posting the answer. +1. Could never have guessed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem was not the name but the Culture inside the Assembly (which is not the same as the language specified into Nuget spec.
Changing the AssemblyCulture from

`[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-GB")]`
to
`[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]`
solved the issue.

I found the warning by toggling diagnostic output during build, as suggested by @ShyamalDesai

```
CSC : warning CS1607: Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'Math' has different culture setting of 'en-GB'
```